# Kinect SDK crashing on background thread for no apparent reason

Tags: c++, kinect

The Kinect SDK throws an access violation exception when opening the NuiImageStream. I have checked and all pointers are valid; the exception is thrown not on my thread; but on a background thread being ran by the Kinect SDK. Any ideas?

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    INuiSensor* sensor;
    NuiCreateSensorByIndex(0,&sensor);
    HRESULT ps = sensor->NuiInitialize(NUI_INITIALIZE_FLAG_USES_DEPTH_AND_PLAYER_INDEX|NUI_INITIALIZE_FLAG_USES_COLOR|NUI_INITIALIZE_FLAG_USES_SKELETON);
    HANDLE mvent = CreateEvent(NULL,FALSE,FALSE,NULL);
    HANDLE streamHandle;
    HRESULT ur = sensor->NuiImageStreamOpen(NUI_IMAGE_TYPE_COLOR,NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_640x480,0,2,mvent,&streamHandle);
```

Comment: Why are you still using the beta? [Version 1.5.0.1](http://kinectforwindows.org) has been available for download for some time

Comment: I'm not using the beta; but I re-installed it now and it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Re-installing the SDK fixed the problem.